# Does Microsoft Edge support rendering in IE8 mode? Is there any solution for this?

Tags: internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, meta-tags, ie-developer-tools, x-ua-compatible

I was using

```
"<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8")
```

in `IE11` to render the an application in `IE8` compatibility mode and I never had any issues. Now `IE11` is going to be replaced with `Edge` and the above solution does not seem to work. Is there a way to resolve this issue? 
Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution to apply in your code to load the IE 8 mode in the Edge browser then I did not get any way to do it.

You can do it from the Edge browser side.

MS Edge Chromium browser comes with the [IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#:%7E:text=What%20is%20IE%20mode%3F,(IE11)%20for%20legacy%20sites.) feature.

IE mode on Microsoft Edge makes it easy to use all of the sites your organization needs in a single browser. It uses the integrated Chromium engine for modern sites, and it uses the Trident MSHTML engine from Internet Explorer 11 (IE11) for legacy sites.

You can configure IE mode by setting a group polices for the MS Edge browser.

Below is the list of relevant policies.

1. [Configure Internet Explorer integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-internet-explorer-integration)

I suggest you **enabled** this policy and set its value to **Internet Explorer mode**.

2. [Send all intranet sites to Internet Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-all-intranet-sites)

With the help of this policy, all intranet sites will be loaded in the IE mode in the MS Edge browser.

3. [Configure the Enterprise Mode Site List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-using-the-configure-the-enterprise-mode-site-list-policy)

You can create sitelist.xml and pass the file address in this policy. You can create the sitelist.xml file manually. If you are not familiar with the content of this file then I suggest you download the [Enterprise Mode Site List Manager (schema v.2)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49974). By using this you can easily create a site list and export it to the XML file.

while creating the site list using Enterprise Mode Site List Manager, you can choose the desired document mode or enterprise mode.

[image]

Sample of site list file:

```
<site-list version="5">
  <created-by>
    <tool>EMIESiteListManager</tool>
    <version>12.0.0.0</version>
    <date-created>01/14/2021 05:45:47</date-created>
  </created-by>
  <site url="localhost">
    <compat-mode>IE8</compat-mode>
    <open-in>IE11</open-in>
  </site>
</site-list>
```

After applying the above policies, I try to launch the test site.

[image]

You can notice that the browser is MS Edge. Page got loaded in the IE mode and page loaded in the IE 8 mode.

Further, you can try to refer to the policies and make the necessary changes according to your requirement and try to make a test on your side.

Comment: @Hariharan S, can you please inform the status of this issue? If the above answer solved the issue, then please try to accept the answer. If you found the solution by yourself then try to post your solution as an answer. If the issue still persists then let us know about the current status for the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed solution. Unfortunately my organization does not provide me access to edit the group policy and make changes to the configuration setting. At the moment I am waiting for the accessibility approval so i can test the solution. I will post an update once there is a progress. Appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Thanks for updating the status of this issue. You can make a test whenever you are available to do it and let us know whether you need any further assistance on this issue. We will try to provide suggestions for that. Thanks for your understanding.