# Edge browser doesn't support document mode defined in X-UA-Compatible meta tag

Tags: microsoft-edge

My application uses IE=9 document mode thru X-UA-Compatible meta tag and some of application pages uses IE =5 as document mode. Our client moving from IE browser to Edge browser. Looks like edge browser doesn't support document mode defined thru X-UA-Compatible meta tag .Is there any way Edge browser can support IE5 document mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it from the Edge browser side.

MS Edge (Chromium) browser comes with the [IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#:%7E:text=What%20is%20IE%20mode%3F,(IE11)%20for%20legacy%20sites.) feature.

IE mode on Microsoft Edge makes it easy to use all of the sites your organization needs in a single browser. It uses the integrated Chromium engine for modern sites, and it uses the Trident MSHTML engine from Internet Explorer 11 (IE11) for legacy sites.

You can configure IE mode by setting a group polices for the MS Edge browser.

Below is the list of relevant policies.

1. [Configure Internet Explorer integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-internet-explorer-integration)

I suggest you enabled this policy and set its value to Internet Explorer mode.

2. [Send all intranet sites to Internet Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-all-intranet-sites)

With the help of this policy, all intranet sites will be loaded in the IE mode in the MS Edge browser.

3. [Configure the Enterprise Mode Site List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-using-the-configure-the-enterprise-mode-site-list-policy)

You can create sitelist.xml and pass the file address in this policy. You can create the sitelist.xml file manually. If you are not familiar with the content of this file then I suggest you download the [Enterprise Mode Site List Manager (schema v.2)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49974). By using this you can easily create a site list and save it to an XML file by following `File-> Save to XML`.

while creating the site list using Enterprise Mode Site List Manager, you can choose the desired document mode or enterprise mode.

[image]

Sample of site list file:

```
<site-list version="6">
  <created-by>
    <tool>EMIESiteListManager</tool>
    <version>12.0.0.0</version>
    <date-created>02/10/2021 01:33:56</date-created>
  </created-by>
  <site url="localhost">
    <compat-mode>IE5</compat-mode>
    <open-in>IE11</open-in>
  </site>
</site-list>
```

After applying the above policies, I try to launch the test site.

[image]

You can notice that the browser is MS Edge. Page got loaded in the IE mode and page loaded in the IE 5 mode.

Further, you can try to refer to the policies and make the necessary changes according to your requirement and try to make a test on your side.

Reference:

1. [Does Microsoft Edge support rendering in IE8 mode? Is there any solution for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65714589/10309381)

Let us know if you have any further questions regarding this issue, I will try to provide suggestions for it.